# Is it secure to use UUID as authentication?

Tags: encryption, authentication, ios

I have an application which uses UUID as an authentication. The UUID is stored as KeyChain inside my iOS application. When I post the UUID, I use https. Is there any way to obtain the password, unless you have physical or remote access to the device? Is this approach strongly discouraged?

[This question](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/157270/using-v4-uuid-for-authentication) addresses the use the UUID as input in a text field, while my question is to use UUID as authentication after a login complete state. If you type it in a text field, the user has to know the UUID. (Talking about my application) First of all, the user does not know his/hers UUID. Second of all, the UUID is encrypted inside KeyChain.

Comment: No. UUID generation is designed with conflict avoidance first and foremost, but they are somewhat predictable, having a consistent device and time-based components.

Comment: So I should not use this approach, but real authentication instead?

Comment: The UUID is made in PHP, how is it predictable?

Comment: It depends what you are trying to protect and what the user experience you’re looking for is. If you are only trying to identify the device and not the user, a secure random string generated by the server and stored on the device during first use would probably be better than a UUID.

Comment: I should probably write a full answer but I’m on a mobile device right now which makes research hard. The UUID spec includes a portion of your mac address and a time-based component. These allow some degree of predictability, especially if your are generating a lot of UUIDs in a short period of time.

Comment: UUIDs are intended to solve the problem of conflicting identifiers in distributed systems, not provide secure randomness for encryption or authentication.

Comment: I have a login page, where you type password and username. After that, I have no form for authentication inside my PHP scripts, except for UUID. I know I should use some sort of authentication after the login script, so I thought the UUID would be secure enough. I am not sure, but I believe the KeyChain made by Apple encrypts the stored values.

Comment: There are several different versions of UUID, and none of them are _required_ to be secure (unguessable). So no, this is not a good idea.

Comment: Ok, what approach should I use?

Comment: @Testtester: If your code will be used in a production environment, you should use an authentication framework that is both popular and built by experts.

Answer (score 6):

**No, you should not use UUIDs as authentication tokens.**

UUIDs are designed to be unique, not to be random or unpredictable. See [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier#Versions) for a list of methods used to generate UUIDs. Let's take, for example,

> **Version 1 (date-time and MAC address)**
>
> Version 1 concatenates the 48-bit MAC address of the "node" (that is, the computer generating the UUID), with a 60-bit timestamp, being the number of 100-nanosecond intervals since midnight 15 October 1582.

If I was an attacker trying to predict the next UUID your server will generate, well once I've seen one one of your UUIDs then I know your MAC address, then I sync my system clock close to yours and I have a high chance of predicting your UUIDs. Your UUIDs are giving you ... maybe the equivalent of a 3 digit PIN's worth of security.

---

Now, you're proposing to use this as a super secret value that only the server and the logged in user know...

I could make some specific suggestions to improve your scheme, but you could probably benefit from doing some broad ground-up reading about "web authentication" and "session management". Here's a good primer to get you started:

https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Session_Management_Cheat_Sheet

Comment: Good answer. I note that type 4 guids are random but not guaranteed to be crypto strength so again, an attacker who knows one type 4 guid can enumerate the space of likely subsequent or previous guids generated.

Comment: If I am not mistaken, UUIDs generated using a cryptographically strong pseudo random number generator can be used as authentication tokens (see the link to the question this is marked a duplicate of).